# How can I use "map" in "perl" to return a hash reference whose key is looked up from an array reference whose value is looked up from another array?

Tags: performance, perl, reference, hashref

I've searched other many Stack questions on map however this requirement is particular and well try as I might I cannot quite get the solution I am looking for, or I think that does exist.

**This question is simply about performance.**

As limited, background, this code segment used in decoding incoming tokens so it's used on every web request and therefore the performance is critical and I know "map" can be used so want to use it.

Here is a *trimmed down* but nevertheless fully working code segment which **I am currently using** and works perfectly well:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw (Dumper);

my $api_token = { array => [ 'user_id', 'session_id', 'expiry' ], max => 3, name => 'session' };
my $token_got = [ 9923232345812112323, 1111323232000000465, 1002323001752323232 ];

my $rt;
for (my $i=0; $i<scalar @{$api_token->{array}}; $i++) {
  $rt->{$api_token->{array}->[$i]} = $token_got->[$i];
}

$rt->{type} = $api_token->{name};
print Dumper ($rt) . "\n";
```

**The question is:**
What is the absolute BEST POSSIBLE PERL CODE to replicate the foreach statement above in terms of performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you only need a hash [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices)

```
my %rt;

@rt{ @{ $api_token->{array} } } = @$token_got;
```

Or, if the hash reference is needed

```
my $rt;

@{ $rt } { @{ $api_token->{array} } } = @$token_got;
```

or with the newer [postfix dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Reference-Slicing), on both array and hash slices, perhaps a bit nicer

```
my $rt;

$rt->@{ $api_token->{array}->@* } = @$token_got;
```

---

One can also do it using
[List::MoreUtils::mesh](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#mesh-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-%5B-ARRAY3-...-%5D), and in one statement

```
my $rt = { mesh @{ $api_token->{array} }, @$token_got };
```

or with [pairwise](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#pairwise-BLOCK-ARRAY1-ARRAY2) from the same library

```
my $rt = { pairwise { $a, $b } @{ $api_token->{array} }, @$token_got };
```

These go via C code if the library gets installed with `List::MoreUtils::XS`.

---

Benchmarked all above, with the tiny datasets from the question (realistic though?), and whatever implementation `mesh`/`pairwise` have they are *multiple times* as *slow* as the others.

On an old laptop with v5.26

```
              Rate use_pair use_mesh use_href use_post use_hash
use_pair  373639/s       --     -36%     -67%     -67%     -68%
use_mesh  580214/s      55%       --     -49%     -49%     -51%
use_href 1129422/s     202%      95%       --      -1%      -5%
use_post 1140634/s     205%      97%       1%       --      -4%
use_hash 1184835/s     217%     104%       5%       4%       --
```

On a server with v5.36 the numbers are around `160%--170%` against `pairwise` (with `mesh` being a bit faster than it, similarly to above)

Of the others, on the laptop the hash-based one is always a few percent quicker, while on a server with v5.36 they are all very close.  Easy to call it a tie.

---

*The following is edit by OP, who timed a 61% speedup (see comments)*

**CHANGED CODE:**

```
@rt{ @{ $api_token->{array} } } = @$token_got; ### much faster onliner replaced the loop. @zdim credit
```

Comment: Now that looks cool... very easy now I see it but somehow it escaped me.
I need to make a reference using 
  ``my $result = \%rt;``    Is it possible to **ref** in a one-liner however yes good!  
OK, I understand that this is not possible in a one-liner due to your postfix dereferencing.

Comment: @MarkArnold Oh right -- that wouldn't be a problem (it's quick), but one can do it directly, added.

Comment: @MarkArnold I haven't timed this, which is your ultimate purpose I guess, but I'd expect this to surely be at least somewhat faster.  Looking into whether there is some other way to speed it up...

Comment: The hash reference code did not work however I will make some benchmarks. You are a great person. I see how it works in perl now much more clearly and how clever you can be.

Comment: You original answer I think is perfect.  I will ``return \%rt;``  in my routine and I think this works for me @zdim    (I will bench it before accepting answer but I think it will be faster).  PairWise looks good... leave it with me and I will come back with benchmarks.  Very great.

Comment: @MarkArnold Added another way, which runs in one statement and could well be fast. Didn't get to benchmark them yet, but will as I'm getting curious :)

Comment: @MarkArnold  Ugh, I had a blooper with the second one, just copied the first an forgot to change to dereferencing (instead of copying dirctly from my tests here!). Fixed

Comment: `                 Rate _original   _return ref
_original   1140251/s          --        -38%
_return ref 1834862/s         61%          --
`
In real-terms on my systems your original code performs 61% faster in real-terms. So that is a 61% saving for every HTPP request.  Thank you.

Comment: @MarkArnold "_61% faster in real-terms._" -- awesome :))  Made my day :).  I updated the last part about my benchmarking, corrected some description.  Apparently, either hash or hashref (but not `pairwise`, which I had hopes for :(.  But by all means time on your systems!

Comment: @MarkArnold  I corrected the statement about using "postfix dereferencing" and added that way as well.  (It behaves exactly the same as the hashref one.)   I kept your edit (it asked me to approve it), with my comment.  Feel free to change if you wish

Comment: @MarkArnold I still had that hashref (second one) goofed up, sorry.  Fixed. Added another library function (`mesh`) but which is sitll much slower and a  few more minor edits.

Comment: To @zdim and anyone interested... the newer postfix dereferencing code is very beautiful and surely the absolute optimum solution. It delivers improved performance by another 0.7% ish on average.  I've actually kept the original code as it's easier to understand overall and the performance is similar. However the question was about performance and actually this **is** the the best performance if only slightly more than the more readable code.  (for me at least!).